# Issuing a warning to users before an app is updated (possibly automatically)

Tags: android, updates, termination, automatic-updates

Whilst preparing a new version of an app I have discovered that the previous version doesn't save the program state to permanent storage in all circumstances. So this information can be lost when an update is performed.

Is there any way to warn users of this bug and advise them on how to ensure that the program state is properly saved before the update is performed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No way to do this before update. If you don't implemented c2dm or custom communication channel   with your app, you cant send message to your users. The best you can do is to add warning message to google play application page and show banner in new version of app and warn users that their data might have been lost and you are very sorry )